# What type of variable to add object to?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I will be using this method to add an entity of Exercise to a Routine.  How can I declare theSelectedRoutine and what type is it?  I'm thinking I set it in this table's parent table's didSelectRow method.

```
-(void)addExercise
{   
    NSError *error = nil;

    Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    exercise.name = selectedExercise;

    [theSelectedRoutine addExerciseObject: exercise];

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [self.routineTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Did you create a corresponding Core Data entity for Selected Routine ?

Comment: No, I have an entity of just Routine.  Maybe I just use `Routine` instead of `Selected Routine`?  This is my core data model: http://www.box.net/shared/static/dpf1tdrxtr.png

Comment: I am not 100% sure I understand your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: Did you see the data model?  I have a table to which I can add entitys of Routine.  Each Routine should have a subtable with that routine's exercises.  This code I posted addes exercise to a routine.  But I need to tell the code which routine to add the exercise to.  That is what theSelectedRoutine should be.  I just don't know how to set the value for it.

Comment: I suppose it could be a module-level variable that you hold, in order to populate it with the user's selections. For instance, it could be a @property that you set when pushing the detail view controller. I'm just guessing here, because I don't know how you're designing your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions.  First, if you don't want to use subclasses for your managed object you can grab the mutable set for the relationship and add your new exercise to it.

```
-(void)addExercise
{   
  NSError *error = nil;
  Exercise *exercise = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
  [exercise setName:selectedExercise];
  [[theSelectedRoutine mutableSetForKey:@"exercise"] addObject:exercise];

  if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to save: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
  }

  [[self routineTableView] reloadData];
}
```

The other object would be to create a subclass for your routine:

```
@interface Routine : NSManagedObject

- (void)addExerciseObject:(NSManagedObject*)exercise;

@end

@implementation Routine

- (void)addExerciseObject:(Employee *)value
{
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    NSMutableSet *primitiveEmployees = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"exercise"];

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"exercise" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveEmployees] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"exercise" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];

    [changedObjects release];
}

@end
```

From there you can then call `-addExerciseObject:` directly.

```
-(void)addExercise
{   
  NSError *error = nil;
  Exercise *exercise = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
  [exercise setName:selectedExercise];
  [theSelectedRoutine addExerciseObject:exercise];

  if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to save: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
  }

  [[self routineTableView] reloadData];
}
```

Note that in either case you **DO NOT** need to case your Exercise object from `-insertNewObjectForEntityForName: inManagedObjectContext:`.  The return for that call is an `id` and `id` never needs to be cast.  In general, casting in Objective-C is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, my question was though, how to I get theSelectedRoutine.  I have not declared it and don't how what to set it to.

Comment: If you have not declared it then you need to as a property and set it where it makes sense.  With the little information you have given I can't be any more specific.